# Database modeling best practice: Dealing with Associations to the same "base"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, associations

I tried to normalize my database model. But I'm clueless how to do it in this case. Giving the following model:

- Customer has many Systems (has_many :systems)
- Cluster has many Systems (has_and_belongs_to_many :systems)

I want to display all Systems of a Customer. That would be: `@customer.systemobjects.each`. That is already working.

Then I could add a System to a Cluster (which I mentioned is a "HABTM" association). In my Customer view I want to show only systems, that are not related to a cluster (also working with `Cluster.includes(:systems).where(systems: { id: sysid }).present?`).

Now my question: I want to display all Clusters (and Systems of that Cluster) of a specific customer, too. But, right now, I only to have the connection to customer through systems. For me, it would be easier, to add a reference to customer also in the cluster object (even though I would have this information already in the system).

Should I add this reference? Does it have something to do with normalization anyway? How would you assess this situation from a best practice point of view for a databases in general and for Ruby On Rails in specific? How would also be the best way, to go through each cluster of a customer, when I have it only through systems (how I could do it in rails?)?

Comment: I'm concerned about your HABTM association between Clusters and Systems.  As I thinking of it you'd want a System to belong_to a Cluster, but not vice versa.

If your intent is for Customers to find the clusters that their systems belong to, you'd have to use some kind of `through` assocation rather than a straightup HABTM which actually has a reasonably narrow application.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand you concerns. For me, a Cluster subsists out of two or more systems (called nodes). But, at some point, there could be a - let's call it - node 3 that is not yet a part of a cluster (but maybe in the future). In most cases I work (Firewalls), it's more common to create a Cluster and add the nodes to it. That's what I'm trying to accomplish here. Do I miss something?

Comment: Its okay that a system not be associated with a cluster in my solution below: in that case the `cluster_id` is nil which is something you can allow without issue.  The concern I have is semantic (and even I suppose more to the point given you don't always have mirrored relationship).  I conceptually do not see how Clusters ever semantically belong to a System, hence HABTM wouldn't apply.  Therefore, it's a one way relationship.  My solution still allows you to specify a cluster and add systems/nodes to it if you like later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd prefer something like this:

```
class Customer
  has_many :systems
  has_many :clusters, through :systems  # expect `clusters_id` in System, which is typical
  # ...other code
end

class System
  belongs_to :customer
  belongs_to :cluster
  # ...other code
end

class Cluster
  has_many :systems
  has_many :customers, through :systems  # expect `customer_id` in System, which is typical
  # ...other code
end
```

This results in three tables, as your model already implies, but uses the systems table as a "hinge" lookup table for the other two without implication that clusters belong to systems (which doesn't make sense IRL as I understand your problem statement).

I often find `has_many :through` is often an easier and better choice than HABTM unless you truly have a mutual belonging relationship.  You can go to the Rails Guides [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) and [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has-many) (guide: "Active Record Associations") for more information on use `:through`.  Definitely worth getting to know that guide for the kind of questions you have (though to be fair, it can take a bit of experience to fully appreciate the various options and how they're helpful).

Now when you want to refer to clusters that a customer has systems within, you merely need to write something like this:

```
  my_customer = Customer.find(some_id)
  customer_clusters = customer.clusters
  customer_systems = customer.systems
```

To find all the customers for a cluster (and so `through` clusters' systems), you'd write something like this:

```
  target_cluster = Cluster.find(some_id)
  cluster_customers = target_cluster.customers
```

If you want a want to produce a hierarchy of those (say, systems of a customer grouped under the clusters they belong to), it'd be something like this:

```
  my_customer = Customer.find(some_id)
  customers_systems = customer.systems.includes(:cluster)  # this brings in the associated cluster records without additional database operations
```

then either iterate or use `group_by` from the resulting data in `customer_systems` depending on how you intend to display or return the data.

Comment: Thank you. That did it. Are you sure, that System needs to have "cluster_id"? Because, in my case, it's working without and I thought in a "System has_and_belongs_to_many Clusters" and "Cluster has_and_belongs_to_many Systems" association it's correct that only the third table "clustes_systems" have both id's in it.

Comment: Typically, you won't need to explicitly specify the cluster_id in System (table: `systems`) if your migration uses a `t.reference`.  I don't know your migration set up, but really all I mean is that `cluster_id` is the foreign key in System to know what cluster it `belongs_to`.  

Note the solution I propose makes no use of a HABTM assocation, but rather uses System as the join table between customers and clusters where needed (though in this case its more than a join table since presumably System has its own data and semantics beyond the join table behavior).